# Vista Home mouse support in HyperV

Tags: windows, virtual-machine

according to the Microsoft website:

> **Supported Client Operating Systems**
>
> Windows Vista x86 (VMs configured with 1- or 2-virtual processors SMP only)
>
> Windows Vista Business x86 Edition with Service Pack 1
>
> Windows Vista Enterprise x86 Edition with Service Pack 1
>
> Windows Vista Ultimate x86 Edition with Service Pack 1

Does anybody know if I can get mouse integration support (and all Integration Services' drivers) in Hyper V for Vista Home? I am using Vista Home, because that is what the OEM license on this machine is for.  Why would Microsoft limit the support to non-Home editions?  Is Hyper-V not to be used for testing?

I want to run 64bit Windows 2008 as a Development Workstation and have a 32bit OS as a VM for those programs/drivers that do not like 64bit.

Using remote desktop instead of the Virtual Machine Connection software works, but that means the network adapter is the "legacy" mode, which may or may not be an issue later.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mouse integration may work, but the reason that Microsoft does not support this situation is because it is against the terms of the [license agreement](http://download.microsoft.com/Documents/UseTerms/Windows%20Vista_Home%20Premium_English_b6fbe7e6-f312-4692-8aee-f5b3d60987b4.pdf) to use Windows Vista Home Basic or Premium in a virtual machine.

Comment: I do not understand the logic behind the agreement, but you did answer my question. Thanks.

What if I was writing a Windows app and wanted to test it on Vista Home or XP Home... Maybe I am missing something here.

Comment: PS - VNC to the rescue

Comment: Technically, you probably can install Vista Home in Hyper V.  You just do it knowing that you are doing it against the license agreement and that you will not be able to get support from Microsoft if you have any problems.  Hyper-V is more targeted towards server virtualization.  Also, Microsoft's stance is that if you are going to be doing any kind of virtualization, it must be done with at least the Professional versions of it's operating system.  Although its inconvenient, if you want to test on Home versions you have to do it on separate hardware (or a separate partition).

Comment: I have it installed - it even read the OEM key automatically from the machine. While there are no errors during the Integration Services install, the drivers do not work for the mouse or network.  Luckily, I can add a Legacy adapter to get network access. With VNC I can accomplish what I needed.  All of this is due to a work task I must do regularly which involves a fake printer, much like Print to PDF but for a different format.  Of course, that fake printer driver is only 32bit.

Thanks again for your help.